# How to fill null with 0 and accumulate `count` with spark `pivot`?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

I have some data of product sales like below:

| product | date | money |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-01 | 60 |
| B | 2020-03 | 80 |
| A | 2020-05 | 41 |
| B | 2020-08 | 50 |
| B | 2020-12 | 76 |
| A | 2020-11 | 76 |

And I want to group the data by `date` and pivot by `product`
My code is below

```
     df.groupBy("date").pivot("product").agg(
      sum("money").as("month-sum"),
      sum(sum("money")).over(Window.orderBy("date").partitionBy("product")).as("cur-cumulative")
    ).orderBy("date").show()
```

And result is

```
|   date|A_month-sum|A_cur-cumulative|B_month-sum|B_cur-cumulative|
+-------+-----------+----------------+-----------+----------------+
|2020-01|         60|              60|       null|            null|
|2020-03|       null|            null|         80|             140|
|2020-05|         41|             181|       null|            null|
|2020-08|       null|            null|         50|             231|
|2020-11|         76|             307|       null|            null|
|2020-12|       null|            null|         76|             383|
```

My expectation is that `null` of `month-sum` can be filled with 0, and `null` of `cur-cumulative` can be filled with value of last row, just like this:

```
|   date|A_month-sum|A_cur-cumulative|B_month-sum|B_cur-cumulative|
+-------+-----------+----------------+-----------+----------------+
|2020-01|         60|              60|          0|               0|
|2020-03|          0|              60|         80|              80|
|2020-05|         41|             101|          0|              80|
|2020-08|          0|             101|         50|             130|
|2020-11|         76|             177|          0|             130|
|2020-12|          0|             177|         76|             206|
+-------+-----------+----------------+-----------+----------------+
```

Is there any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `.na.fill(0)` before doing the cumulative sums:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df2 = df
    .groupBy("date")
    .pivot("product")
    .agg(sum("money"))

val df3 = df2
    .na.fill(0)
    .select(
        col("date") +: 
        df2.columns.tail.flatMap(x => 
            Seq(
                col(x).as(x + "_month-sum"),
                sum(x).over(Window.orderBy("date")).as(x + "_cur-cumulative")
            )
        ): _*
    )
    .orderBy("date")

df3.show
+-------+-----------+----------------+-----------+----------------+
|   date|A_month-sum|A_cur-cumulative|B_month-sum|B_cur-cumulative|
+-------+-----------+----------------+-----------+----------------+
|2020-01|       60.0|            60.0|        0.0|             0.0|
|2020-03|        0.0|            60.0|       80.0|            80.0|
|2020-05|       41.0|           101.0|        0.0|            80.0|
|2020-08|        0.0|           101.0|       50.0|           130.0|
|2020-11|       76.0|           177.0|        0.0|           130.0|
|2020-12|        0.0|           177.0|       76.0|           206.0|
+-------+-----------+----------------+-----------+----------------+
```